# C++ Explicit templated function instantiation for templated class of different type

Tags: c++, templates, visual-c++

I am trying to explicitly instantiate a templated function of type U inside a templated class of type T.  My code below generates a warning and the linker does not find the explicit instantiation of `ReinterpretAs()`.  Can anyone spot the error or advise on how to do this?  I am using VC++ 2010.

```
template<typename T> 
class Matrix
{
  public:
    template<typename U> Matrix<U> ReinterpretAs() const;
};

template<typename T>
template<typename U>
Matrix<U> Matrix<T>::ReinterpretAs() const
{
   Matrix<U> m;
   // ...
   return m;
}


// Explicit instantiation.
template class Matrix<int>;
template class Matrix<float>;

template Matrix<float>  Matrix<int>::ReinterpretAs<float>();
template Matrix<int>    Matrix<float>::ReinterpretAs<int>();
```

The last two lines above give a compiler warning:

```
warning #536: no instance of function template "Matrix<T>::ReinterpretAs 
[with T=float]" matches the specified type
```

Thank you in advance, Mark

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You're missing the `const`.

```
template class Matrix<int>;
template class Matrix<float>;

template Matrix<float>  Matrix<int>::ReinterpretAs<float>() const;
template Matrix<int>    Matrix<float>::ReinterpretAs<int>() const;
```