# Template function defined in cpp file?

Tags: c++, templates, variadic-templates

I have the following piece of code where I'm using two template functions to access elements of a tuple. The `print` function will have code that requires more files to be `#include`ed and I don't want code bloating if I was to include it in a header, given that template functions are defined in a header. Is there a way I could move the function definitions into a cpp file and avoid recursive / duplicate inclusions?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <tuple>
#include <iostream>

template<std::size_t I = 0, typename... Tp>
inline typename std::enable_if<(I >= sizeof...(Tp)), void>::type
print(std::tuple<Tp...> &/*t*/) { }
        
template<std::size_t I = 0, typename... Tp>
inline typename std::enable_if<(I < sizeof...(Tp)), void>::type
print(std::tuple<Tp...> &t) { 
    std::cout << std::get<I>(t) << std::endl; 
}
        
int main()
{
    std::tuple<int, std::string, char> t = std::make_tuple(10, "Hello", 'A');
    print<0>(t);
    print<1>(t);
    print<2>(t);
    print<4>(t);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Unless you manually want to instantiate the template for all the template parameters you would use, no: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/495021/why-can-templates-only-be-implemented-in-the-header-file

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Storing C++ template function definitions in a .CPP file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/115703/storing-c-template-function-definitions-in-a-cpp-file)

Comment: For the printing i would implement the output stream operator for the types you need to print. So your implementation would be complete and somewhere you define how the objects need to be written to the stream.

Comment: @NathanOliver How would I instantiate the template for one parameter for example? For instance i have a function - 
`template <status_point_type NOTIFIABLE_TYPE, class ... NOTIFIABLES>
template <std::size_t I, typename... Tp>
inline typename std::enable_if<(I < sizeof...(Tp)), void>::type
BasicAttributeNotifier<NOTIFIABLE_TYPE, NOTIFIABLES ...>::notify(std::tuple<Tp...> &t) { }`

Comment: You would need to do something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8302407/c-explicit-templated-function-instantiation-for-templated-class-of-different-t) to instantiate the class and then the member function.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I explicitly instantiate a template function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4933056/how-do-i-explicitly-instantiate-a-template-function)